Create SQLite View From Two Tables Recursively
I have a column on Table A with numbers and a column on Table B different set of numbers.
How do i create a view of table A numbers with a second column of the closest numbers from B.
---Table ColA---|---Table ColB---
13     | 22
25     | 49
22     | 11
33     | 36
I want for the VIEW results to be
---View ColA---|---View ColB---
13     | 11
25     | 22
22     | 22
33     | 36

Depending on how much data you are looking at and if this is only a one off query vs calling it several times, a quick and dirty solution could be to simply cross join the tables, ...
... and using the functions ROW_NUMBER (link to the documentation) to select the correct entry the ABS(link to the documentation) function to calculate the absolute difference between the to columns and simply wrap it all in a subquery, to keep things clean.
Could look something like this:
SELECT t1num, t2num FROM (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition BY t1.num ORDER BY t1.num, ABS(t1.num - t2.num) ) rowNum,
        t1.num t1num, 
        t2.num t2num 
    FROM Table1 t1 CROSS JOIN Table2 t2) SubQuery
 WHERE rowNum = 1


What if its a large number or rows? Ran this, it works but slow on large numbers of rows. Can it be done with a view?

Well you can put it into a view, but this will not improve the performance. How the performance can be improved depends on the amount of rows of both tables, how the resulting data is being used, How many colums, apart the two columns are you selecting, How often does the data change, Are you selecting the whole join or only a part of the data, ... ? It really depends. Let's say the data doesn't change, but you need to retrieve the result often you, could save the result in a temp-table, an than only query the temp-table.

But maybe someone else has a better solution. I would need a bit more context to optimize the result.

What im trying to do is create a alternative view to a table A. Table A doesn't have a time associated with it but it does have a row id(order of data populated and unique throughout all tables rows, no row will have the same input id), so im looking in Table B for the nearest row id  and getting its time so i can see when the row in Table A occurs.  It would be nice to make that into a view so i can keep it separate from the real tables.

Well I this case, create a view is easy just prepend CREATE VIEW  to the select (link to an example). If you can alter the tables you could maybe add a foreign key to one of the Tables and write the ID of the other table in it and than just join the tables over ID's. If not I think you are stuck with the CROSS JOIN. Just to know, how many rows per table are you about joining?

Without knowing the Data if both tables have the same amount of entries and the correlation is 1:1 and I can assume all entries are in the right order you could use ROW_NUMBER (link to adocumentation) on both tables an Join them over with that number/column. But this will only work, if the data in both tables are as mentioned above in the "correct" order.

Unfortunately they are not 1:1 more like 1:30, and rows are over 100k. It looks like im going to have to add a foreign key like you've noted because im not seeing a quicker way to do this. The Cross join is taking too long.
